# How to fail an Ansible task if executable not exists?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Part of my Ansible playbook is K3S cluster creation.

For a server node I have these tasks:

```
<...>

    - name: Retrieve K3S installation status
      command: which k3s
      changed_when: false
      failed_when: false
      register: k3s_installed

    - name: Install K3S unless already installed
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -
      async: 300
      poll: 5
      retries: 3
      when: k3s_installed.rc not in [0]

<...>
```

The first task checks if K3S is already installed on the host and captures result in `k3s_installed` variable. And the second task installs the K3S if the `k3s` command is missing.

I would like to go a bit further and update the second tasks with a check that `k3s` executable after installation exists. If not, it should fail and try again (I have `retries: 3`). Something like:

```
failed_when: <condition that checks if k3s executable still not exists>
```

All Ansible examples I found have `failed_when` condition based on the current task execution result (like task output or exit code). What would be the proper way to implement this check?

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***Update the second tasks with a check that k3s executable after installation exists.***

A: Create a script that checks what you want, and use the module [*script*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html) instead of *shell*. Make this task idempotent by using the parameter [*creates*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html#parameter-creates). For example,

```yaml
  - script:
      cmd: "{{ playbook_dir }}/bin/install_k3s.sh"
      creates: /usr/local/bin/k3s
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

Use [*async*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html) if the script takes too much time. See [ansible: combine loop (until) with conditional (when)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462074/ansible-combine-loop-until-with-conditional-when) on how to register the result, test it, and repeat the script until a condition is met.

You can do the same by using the module *shell*. The advantage of the module *script* is the simplicity of testing. You can easily test the standalone script on the remote host(s) first. When the script does what you want, use the module *script*.

Answer (score 0):

Good Ansible tasks make the thing requested by their parameters happen, or fail. Maybe you supplement things with extra tasks asserting various things, but make tasks not doing things obvious. Fail fast is good.

In this case, install the k3s software. Usually I would recommend using a package manager. Standardize how software archives are installed, upgraded, audited, and rolled back.  Ansible package module can do this for a variety of package managers, install a package if it doesn't exist, error if that cannot be done.

Unfortunately, this script is not a proper package. I do not like software install scripts. Not tracked by package manager. Downloading random scripts and binaries from the internet sometimes. Not conforming to conventions of my preferred distro. And unreliable on how they behave on error conditions, or when run again.

Anyway, you can't really tack on a "file exists on a remote host" task to a task that runs some arbitrary script. Ansible runs one low-level script doing real work per task. shell module only has the return code of the script to work from (plus stdout or stderr if you write a clever failed_when expression).

Rather, follow the install task with another task, running a simple k3s command. Getting the version or usage text, or doing some real work with it, or something. If it does not exist on $PATH, Ansible will error as you might expect. Substitute the actual option that does nothing but has a zero return code.

```yaml
# Install K3S goes here

- name: Check K3S installed
  command: k3s
```

Ansible does not have good ways of retrying a set of tasks, such as these extra checks after installing the software. Also I would want to see the failure modes to assess if a retry would be helpful. So skip using until keyword for now.

Rather, focus efforts on improving the script, or building it into a proper package archive. Either way, likely you want to download and customize your own build, rather than downloading from the internet. Just package maintainer things.